# How to create a DB design for chat feature?

Tags: database-design, chat

We need to create a chat feature in our web app based on spring MVC.

There will be two kinds of chat one-to-one chat and group chat.

For group chat I have come up with following schema.

```
Table = group_chat 

User_id, message, message_on (datetime), group_id
```

I am not sure of the one-to-one chat though.

One to one chat may happen outside of a group or within a group between two group members.

Please help

Answer (score 5):

Your question is a bit open ended, due to the fact that we don't know anything about your architecture or requirements. However, having two separate tables for what is essentially the same type of data looks like a code smell to me. I'd probably begin with a structure like this and iterate over it depending on how it performs.

```
USERS
user_id
username
password

GROUP
group_id
name

GROUP_MEMBERS
group_id
user_id

MESSAGE
message_id
timestamp
from_user_id
destination_type (enum - group, user)
destination_id
```

Any additions you make to your chat feature are then automatically propagated to both peer-to-peer and group chat. Of course, that also requires that your code follows the same principle of combining both types of chat into the same classes.

Comment: Hi!! I find your answer very interesting. But there is something that's not clear to me: how can I obtain the list of the 5 more recent dicussions (either private or group) in which a specific user has been a active? Can you write a sample query?

Comment: Another question: the field "destination_id" is a foreign key related to which field(s)? Group_id.... or both group_id and user_id?